# Add a string to the end of column 1 using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file whose head looks like this:

```
>PZ7180000000004_TX nReads=26 cov=9.436
>PZ7180000031590 nReads=3 cov=2.59465
>PZ7180000027934 nReads=5 cov=2.32231
>PZ456916 nReads=1 cov=1
>PZ7180000037718 nReads=9 cov=6.26448
>PZ7180000000004_TY nReads=86 cov=36.4238
>PZ7180000000067_AF nReads=16 cov=12.0608
>PZ7180000031591 nReads=4 cov=3.26022
>PZ7180000024036 nReads=14 cov=5.86079
>PZ15501_A nReads=1 cov=1
```

I want to add the string `_nogroup` onto the first column of each line that does not have `_XX` already designated (i.e. the 1st column on the 1st line is fine but the `1st` column on the `2nd` line should read `>PZ7180000031590_nogroup`).

Can I do this using `awk` like to use the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk '!($1 ~ /_[a-zA-Z]{2}$/) {$1=$1 "_nogroup"} 1' file
>PZ7180000000004_TX nReads=26 cov=9.436
>PZ7180000031590_nogroup nReads=3 cov=2.59465
>PZ7180000027934_nogroup nReads=5 cov=2.32231
>PZ456916_nogroup nReads=1 cov=1
>PZ7180000037718_nogroup nReads=9 cov=6.26448
>PZ7180000000004_TY nReads=86 cov=36.4238
>PZ7180000000067_AF nReads=16 cov=12.0608
>PZ7180000031591_nogroup nReads=4 cov=3.26022
>PZ7180000024036_nogroup nReads=14 cov=5.86079
>PZ15501_A_nogroup nReads=1 cov=1
```

Comment: @anubhava: somehow it is adding "_nogroup" to all elements in the first column for me. i'm having GNU Awk 3.1.6. {2} not supported ??

Comment: @anubhava: yes that will work. But i was just wondering why {2} didn work for me, that's all... perhaps {2} not supported in my awk version. will chk on that. thanks.

Comment: @anubhava it puts one space instead of tab in the output file. Is there a way to convert that single space to tab?

Comment: If input file is tab delimited then use `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` at the start